# Trying to make a simple drum machine with Python, how would I get it to make some noise?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to make a drum machine using Python. I want have it so it plays a sound when the user presses a key.

Using the msvcrt model, I got the it to recognize keypresses but I'm wondering how I'll get to it make some noise after that.

Here's my current code:

```
from msvcrt import getch
    while True:
        key= ord(getch())
        if key == 27: #the esc key
        break
        if key == 113: #the w key
            #play sound
```

Now how would I get around doing this? Is there a specific module I can use for things like this or would I have to make it so it plays downloaded files upon pressing the corresponding key?

Comment: look into the supercollider, it has built in drum machines.

Comment: Looks very useful, will look into that, thank you.

Comment: alternatively if you want an aio solution, grab a copy of sonicpi (it's unfortunately written in ruby). It is primarily used for 'algo-raving' or livecoding music at a party

Comment: Well, I think supercollider is just the kind of thing I'd want in this project so I'll think I'll learn that and look into it though, thank you for the extra info though!

Comment: Not my code, but think it is a good example how to solve your problem in pygame: https://github.com/LukeD63/Pygame-Simple-Drum/blob/master/Pygame%20Simple%20Drum.py

Comment: See [Playing Random Sound on Keypress \[Python\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494794/playing-random-sound-on-keypress-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*answering as a question to close this item out*

Try using [supercollider](http://supercollider.github.io/), from the github page

> SuperCollider is a platform for audio synthesis and algorithmic composition, used by musicians, artists, and researchers working with sound. It is free and open source software available for Windows, macOS, and Linux.
>
> SuperCollider features three major components:
>
> scsynth, a real-time audio server, forms the core of the platform. It features 400+ unit generators ("UGens") for analysis, synthesis, and processing. Its granularity allows the fluid combination of many known and unknown audio techniques, moving between additive and subtractive synthesis, FM, granular synthesis, FFT, and physical modelling. You can write your own UGens in C++, and users have already contributed several hundred more to the sc3-plugins repository.
>
> sclang, an interpreted programming language. It is focused on sound,
> but not limited to any specific domain. sclang controls scsynth via
> Open Sound Control. You can use it for algorithmic composition and
> sequencing, finding new sound synthesis methods, connecting your app
> to external hardware including MIDI controllers, network music,
> writing GUIs and visual displays, or for your daily programming
> experiments. It has a stock of user-contributed extensions called
> Quarks. scide is an editor for sclang with an integrated help system.

Broadly speaking you would wrap your existing code around a unit generator for an individual drum hit/instrument or an drum loop which would allow you to map your keyboard commands to create something like a drum machine.

Comment: Just a question though, are there any good specific sources I can learn to do this or will just some good old googling do? Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately SC is extremely poorly documented (bascially have to go to the github for any real documentation). Additionally, while the basics are relatively straightforward, a lot of the music theory principles are poorly explained (so its almost better to pick up a book on sound engineering)