# Playing Random Sound on Keypress [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I decide to write a small script, that would play random sound on a keypress.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import keyboard, string, random
from playsound import playsound

path = "C:\\Users\\vilem\\Documents\\My_Stuff\\Py_Projects\\Temp\\keypress" #path to sound files

letter = string.ascii_letters #gets list of lover and uper case letters
digit = string.digits #gets list of numbers

while True:
    mp3Select = random.choice(os.listdir(path)) #selects random sound
    keypress = str(path + "\\" + mp3Select) #gets the path to the random sound

def keyboardPress():
    if keyboard.is_pressed(letter): #checks if letter was pressed
        playsound(keypress) #plays random sound
    elif keyboard.is_pressed(digit): #checks if digit was pressed
        playsound(keypress) #plays random sound

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            keyboardPress()
        except:
            pass

main()
```

Now, the problem is that I don't get any output and no error. I run the script from cmd and even if I make it print some variable like `letter` it's always stuck and when I stop it with "Ctrl + C" it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vilem\Documents\My_Stuff\Py_Projects\Temp\typing.py", line 13, in <module>
    mp3Select = random.choice(os.listdir(path))
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: in `main()`, what error do you get if you remove the exception handler?

Comment: Python code is run sequentially line-by-line. Your execution is getting stuck in that `while True` loop before you even define any function or et to run `main()`

Answer (score 0):

what you do to read key is wrong,
in python 3 try:

```
pressedKey=input()
```

then check the input to play a sound based on that.
something like:

```
if(presedKey is letter) or (is digit)
```

and that

```
while True:
mp3Select = random.choice(os.listdir(path)) #selects random sound
keypress = str(path + "\\" + mp3Select) #gets the path to the random sound
```

is not belong there, remove it, you can try something like:

```
import os
import keyboard, string, random
from playsound import playsound

path = "C:\\Users\\vilem\\Documents\\My_Stuff\\Py_Projects\\Temp\\keypress" #path to sound files

letter = string.ascii_letters #gets list of lover and uper case letters
digit = string.digits #gets list of numbers    
def keyboardPress():
    mp3Select = random.choice(os.listdir(path)) #selects random sound
    keypress = str(path + "\\" + mp3Select) #gets the path to the random sound
    while True:
        if letter.find(keyboard.read_key())>-1:
            playsound(keypress)
            break

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            keyboardPress()
        except:
            pass

main()
```

and you do not have different directory and sounds for digits and letters, so different action when pressing different type of keys is not necessary.

Comment: So this solution works, but it's really slow, it takes a while for the sound to play and sometimes it doesn't play at all, any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this to achieve the functionality you are after:

```
import os
import keyboard, string, random
from playsound import playsound
path = "C:\\Users\\vilem\\Documents\\My_Stuff\\Py_Projects\\Temp\\keypress" #path to sound files
letter = string.ascii_letters #gets list of lover and uper case letters
digit = string.digits #gets list of numbers

mp3Select = random.choice(os.listdir(path)) #selects random sound
keypress = str(path + "\\" + mp3Select) #gets the path to the random sound

pressedKey = input('Press any key then ENTER')

def keyboardPress():
    if pressedKey in letter or digit:
        playsound(keypress)

def main():
        keyboardPress()

main()
```

if you want, you can add the pressedKey and keypress definitions into the main function in a loop to continuously ask for a new key, and play a new sound